# Pandas - Select rows of a dataframe that contains a certain regex in ANY column

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas

Good morning

given a dataframe that contains text data such as:

```
df = pandas.DataFrame({
    'a':['first', 'second', 'third'], 
    'b':['null', 'third', 'first']})
```

I can select rows that contain the word `'first'` by:

```
df.a.str.contains('first') | df.b.str.contains('first')
```

which would yield

```
0     True
1    False
2     True
dtype: bool
```

To apply the same condition to to dozens of columns I could use `isin`, but it seems not to work if I need to substitute `'first'` with a regex, as in `regex = '(?=.*first)(?=.*second)'`.

Is there a more pythonic and elegant way to select on multiple columns, rather than just concatenating several single-column `df.<column_name>.str.contains(regex)` conditions with `|` in the code? Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why don't we use `applymap` on the entire data frame. This will be different than working the columns but would make it easier for your to apply if-else conditions to (I hope):

```
In [62]: l = ['first', 'second']

In [63]: df
Out[63]: 
        a      b
0   first   null
1  second  third
2   third  first

In [64]: df.appl
df.apply     df.applymap  

In [64]: df.applymap(lambda v: True if v in l else False)
Out[64]: 
       a      b
0   True  False
1   True  False
2  False   True
```

#### Update:

(Thanks to @Pythonic for this update)

We can supply regex in `applymap` like so:

```
regex = '(^fi)'
df.applymap(lambda v: bool(re.search(regex, v)))
## -- End pasted text --
Out[38]: 
       a      b
0   True  False
1  False  False
2  False   True
```

Following example is with re.flags enabled:

```
In [44]: df = pandas.DataFrame({
   ....:     'a':['First', 'second', 'NULL'], 
   ....:     'b':['null', 'third', 'first']})

In [45]: regex = re.compile('(^fi)', flags=re.IGNORECASE)

In [46]: df.applymap(lambda v: bool(re.search(regex_ignore_case, v)))
Out[46]: 
       a      b
0   True  False
1  False  False
2  False   True
```

Comment: Thanks. Sort of works, with 2 drawbacks: misses the case-insensitivity of `contains(case=False)` and does not work in the null case of an empty list of words

Comment: The whole point of `applymap` is that you can apply a function on every cell of the data frame. So, I think your two drawbacks are covered if you expand the function further. Need help with that ?

Comment: All right, after digging into `pandas.core.strings` here's the answer using `applymap`: `df.applymap(lambda v: bool(re.search(regex, v))).any(axis=1)`

Comment: Thanks. probably also worth adding that to avoid case-matching, the regex must be compiled thus: `regex_ignore_case = re.compile(regex, flags=re.IGNORECASE)`, and then `regex_ignore_case` is fed into the expression above